# jQuery: call another event then continue executing current event

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling

Curious how to execute the original event after another event.  For instance, what is the proper way to chain events?

Because I don't have a simple example, I'll try to create one:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/t6635/)

```
$('#select').on( 'click', function(event) {

   $('#clearSelectButton').click();                  // clears this select list

   // still want to select an option from 
   // the select list (continuing original event)

});
```

Comment: Mhm... that sounds like you need callbacks or promises.

Comment: You could use a Deferred object or a promise more info here:
http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: If your use case actually involves `select` with multiple selection then you will do nothing but break the basic usability that any user expects.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: don't read too far into the example :)

Comment: Well ok, I've had a similar issue not too long ago, ended up with some hackiness that could be of help, however, you're using a `click` handler which fires *after* the user has made a selection (which may overlap with the previous selection), so you'll probably want to switch to `mousedown` before moving onwards.

Comment: @Meryovi yes but how would one implement the callback, I've looked into `$.when().done()` but the goal is to end with a selection, which is the clicked `option`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: I think you're right

Comment: If you want just to pass the event, you can create an hierarchy of elements and return true or false if you have consumed the event. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zWdKq/) is a small example where it consumes or not the event.

Comment: Well if you want only a single option selected, you could try a non-multiple select and add styling with one of the many plugins available out there ([Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) comes to mind).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I'm using Select2 (horrible name for plugin), but no, there will be multiple selections. I just wanted to let you know that I didn't give too much thought to the example (the time of events), I was concentrating on the chaining/order of events, and not so much the event being called.  I was hoping there would be a way to pause/store/continue event execution, but my hopes weren't that high given JS's history of event handling.

Comment: @vol7ron Yeah, I see. Thing is, the event *does* execute, the problem is that the `click` event in this case (multiple `select`) has already been handled by the browser by the time your handler executes, hence resetting the selected options will undo the click's default action. You can see that this is the case [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t6635/2/) - you can't prevent the default action because it has already been handled by the browser (yeah, that goes against how the `click` event usually works).

Comment: So in this case your `.on('click'` handler executes after the click event has been handled by the browser, you can't resume something that has already happened. There's ways to replicate the said behavior, however I'm unsure of what you're actually trying to achieve so it is hard to answer sorry.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: correct. I'm going to close this question and reopen another one.  I have something close to working using  `mousedown`/`mouseup`, aside from the initial click (though that was the problem originally), it's still better to be more explicit in what's going on